# Como modificar o caminho da view com htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Estou criando um `htaccess` para redirecionar a URL, por exemplo:

tenho o seguinte URL:

```
   www.site.com.br/view/html/cliente.html
   www.site.com.br/view/html/relatorio/demonstrativoDeDebito.html
```

e gostaria que ficasse assim

```
   www.site.com.br/cliente
   www.site.com.br/relatorio/demonstrativoDeDebito
```

meu `htaccess` e esse, ele apenas remove o HTML no final dos arquivos:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `RewriteBase` e configure o caminho todo no RegEx e o arquivo .htaccess deve ficar na pasta raiz.

Você deve usar para apontar tudo para a pasta `/view/html`:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view/html/$1.html
```

Também pode verificar se o caminho já começa com `view/html/` e ignorar estes:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(?!view/html/.*)(.*)$ view/html/$2.html
```